# Dictionary for storing orders - DataStructure

Tags: c#

I have some orders coming down the wire quite frequently, I need to store them and build an aggregation out of them. An order will have an ID and there will be an instrument type associated with it. The orders can also have some events attached to it, like say add, update or remove. If it's an update event, then there will not be an instrument type attached with the order, but the order id will be same. For ex: if I have an order for instrument "xyz" with order id 100, later on I can get an event to update the order which has an id 100 by $20, and there will not be an instrument type present with that event (order).

Once I receive an order, I need to build an order book for unique instruments, for example instrument "xyz" should contain all recieved orders for it inside the orderbook.

My question is how efficiently can I store this and what kind of data structure should I use for it?

An Order looks something like this:

```
public class Order
{
  public Order(Action add, int id, string instrument, int price)
}
```

An Orderbook:

```
public class OrderBook
{
 public string Instrument;
public List<Order> AllOrders;
}
```

**Option 1:**

Update a `Dictionary<int,OrderBook>` when I receive an order, with key as order id, and create an order book for the instrument.

**Issue**: This will take care of the update events, I can check whether the order already exists, and then update the order book. However an instrument type should only have one order book, and this condition is violated here, as for instrument "xyz" there could be multiple Add orders coming through, and also makes the manipulation difficult.

**Option 2:**

Update a dictionary of `Dictionary<OrderBook, List<int>>`, with values as the order id's.

**Issue**: This will take care of the above issue, however when I get an update event, I'll have to check through every list of values (i.e list of order id's) to see whether the order exists already, since the instrument type is going to be empty and I cannot look by the OrderBook key.

Orders are coming down at real time, and the operation for storing and retrieving has has to be bit more efficient(if not O(1) then O(logn)), is there a better way to structure this please?

**NOTE**: An OrderBook is an aggregation of all orders for an instrument and will be unique for the instrument. An order will be for an instrument for a particular price, and there will be many orders for the same instrument. **I get the orders along with the event from someone else(a third party lib), and I'm responsible for building the orderbook.**

Comment: Why do you have `Instrument` in both the OrderBook and `Order`?

Comment: You have instrument in both the classes Order and OrderBook. Why so?

Answer (score 0):

I see this issue as combination of two child issues.

1. You are tracking the OrderID for across the inputs.
2. You are maintaining unique Orderbook per item.

In such case, I would suggest maintain both the dictionaries
Alternatively, you can convert the `List<order>` to `dictionary <int, order>` in orderbook to simplify the search with the orderbook.

For the option 1, you mentioned

> However an instrument type should only have one order book, and this
>   condition is violated here

You are not going to have multiple orderbooks, but maintaining the reference of the same order book across the dictionary entries.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
public class Order
    {
        public Action Action { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }

        public Order(Action add, int id, int price){
            //Initialize
        }
    }

    public class Instrument
    {
        public string InstrumentName { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<int, Order> OrderBook { get; set; }

        public Instrument(string instrument)
        {
            InstrumentName = instrument;
            //OrderBook = new List<Order>();
        }

        public void AddOrder(Order order)
        {
            //Check order exist condition
            OrderBook.Add(order.Id, order);
        }
    }
```

Then use `List<Instrument>`

I guess it should work for you. Let me know if any issue in this.

Comment: I get the order from someone else, and also your solution does not handle the case of an update event when there is no instrument present.

Comment: Yes you need to check if instrument already exist, otherwise you can create one. Its one time process.